# Unable to change text font/weight or anything on table thead?

Tags: html, css

So I am having trouble trying to change the font-family,weight, and size for the `thead`of my `table`.

I have tried adding `style=""`and inserting code that way, but nothing changes still.

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
<table>
<thead style="font-weight:bold;">Food & Prices</thead>
<tr class="special">
    <td>Item</td>
    <td>Cost</td>
    <td>Weight</td>
    <td>Availability</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Chocolate Waffle</td>
    <td>$394.48</td>
    <td>21LBS</td>
    <td>Sedro Woolley</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Sprinkle Waffle</td>
    <td>$12.04</td>
    <td>5LBS</td>
    <td>Sedro Woolley & Burlington</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Cherry Waffle</td>
    <td>$244.00</td>
    <td>4.5LBS</td>
    <td>Mount Vernon</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Tamale Waffle</td>
    <td>$1.99</td>
    <td>100LBS</td>
    <td>Sedro Woolley & Stanwood</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Blueberry Waffle</td>
    <td>$4.05</td>
    <td>1.24LBS</td>
    <td>Burlington & Mount Vernon</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>M&M Waffle</td>
    <td>$30.40</td>
    <td>1.1LBS</td>
    <td>Stanwood</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Coconut Waffle</td>
    <td>$0.99</td>
    <td>0.01LBS</td>
    <td>Sedro Woolley</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Unicorn Dust Waffle</td>
    <td>$666.66</td>
    <td>66LBS</td>
    <td>Sedro Woolley & Mount Vernon</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Ketchup Waffle</td>
    <td>$439.33</td>
    <td>19.4LBS</td>
    <td>Burlington</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Strawberry Waffle</td>
    <td>$5.50</td>
    <td>3.2LBS</td>
    <td>All Locations</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Coffee Waffle</td>
    <td>$3.12</td>
    <td>3.2LBS</td>
    <td>Burlington & Mount Vernon</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>School Lunch Waffle</td>
    <td>$2.50</td>
    <td>0.25LBS</td>
    <td style="font-weight:bold;">No longer in stock by demand!</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Spoon Waffle</td>
    <td>$31.01</td>
    <td>2LBS</td>
    <td>All Locations</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Paper Waffle</td>
    <td>$58.48</td>
    <td>0.1LBS</td>
    <td>Stanwood</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Tears from a God Waffle</td>
    <td>$77777777.77</td>
    <td>$777LBS</td>
    <td>Sedro Wolley</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
table{
width:1000px;
margin:auto;
text-align:center;
display:block;
}
table td{
width:250px;
padding-top:5px;
padding-bottom:5px;
}
table tr{
border-bottom:1px solid #444;
}
.special{
font-weight:bold;
}
.ok {
font-weight:bold;
font-family:Verdana;
font-size:22px;
color:#444;
font-weight:bold;
}
table thead{
font-weight:bold;
font-family:Verdana;
font-size:22px;
color:#444;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You still need to define a cell. Like this:

```
<thead style="font-weight:bold;"><tr><th>Food & Prices</th><tr></thead>
```

If you want your header to span to coumns, add colspan="2" like this:

```
<thead style="font-weight:bold;"><tr><th colspan="2">Food & Prices</th></tr></thead>
```

see jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/nxp86d59/2/

Comment: I'ts actually `<thead><tr><td>` you are missing `<tr>`

Answer (score 0):

The  tag goes around your row containing the headers for your columns, so your thead should look like this

```
<thead>
    <tr class="special">
        <td>Item</td>
        <td>Cost</td>
        <td>Weight</td>
        <td>Availability</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

For you heading you may just have to make it a h3 or something or another row with a td with colspan=4

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=4>Food & Prices</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="special">
        <td>Item</td>
        <td>Cost</td>
        <td>Weight</td>
        <td>Availability</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Sorry - those should be th tags in the thead as pointed out by Julien Grégoire

Answer (score 0):

If you use the thead element there should be no direct children of table that are tr elements - they must be within a tbody element - Also be cool and change `&` to html friendly `&amp;` :-)

See below:

```
<div class="box">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="4">Food &amp; Prices</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th>Item</th>

        <th>Cost</th>

        <th>Weight</th>

        <th>Availability</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Chocolate Waffle</td>

        <td>$394.48</td>

        <td>21LBS</td>

        <td>Sedro Woolley</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Sprinkle Waffle</td>

        <td>$12.04</td>

        <td>5LBS</td>

        <td>Sedro Woolley &amp; Burlington</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Cherry Waffle</td>

        <td>$244.00</td>

        <td>4.5LBS</td>

        <td>Mount Vernon</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Tamale Waffle</td>

        <td>$1.99</td>

        <td>100LBS</td>

        <td>Sedro Woolley &amp; Stanwood</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Blueberry Waffle</td>

        <td>$4.05</td>

        <td>1.24LBS</td>

        <td>Burlington &amp; Mount Vernon</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>M&amp;M Waffle</td>

        <td>$30.40</td>

        <td>1.1LBS</td>

        <td>Stanwood</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Coconut Waffle</td>

        <td>$0.99</td>

        <td>0.01LBS</td>

        <td>Sedro Woolley</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Unicorn Dust Waffle</td>

        <td>$666.66</td>

        <td>66LBS</td>

        <td>Sedro Woolley &amp; Mount Vernon</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Ketchup Waffle</td>

        <td>$439.33</td>

        <td>19.4LBS</td>

        <td>Burlington</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Strawberry Waffle</td>

        <td>$5.50</td>

        <td>3.2LBS</td>

        <td>All Locations</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Coffee Waffle</td>

        <td>$3.12</td>

        <td>3.2LBS</td>

        <td>Burlington &amp; Mount Vernon</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>School Lunch Waffle</td>

        <td>$2.50</td>

        <td>0.25LBS</td>

        <td style="font-weight:bold;">No longer in stock by demand!</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Spoon Waffle</td>

        <td>$31.01</td>

        <td>2LBS</td>

        <td>All Locations</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Paper Waffle</td>

        <td>$58.48</td>

        <td>0.1LBS</td>

        <td>Stanwood</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Tears from a God Waffle</td>

        <td>$77777777.77</td>

        <td>$777LBS</td>

        <td>Sedro Wolley</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the jsfiddle

You html is what was needed correction. You did not close the `<thead>` element properly. and you failed to use the `<tbody>` element. Now it should work properly

**NOTE:**

It would be more better if you put the 'Foods and Prices ' somewhere above the table so hat it would not disturb the table contents.

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="table-heading">
        Food & Prices
    </div>
<table>
<thead style="font-weight:bold;">
<tr class="special">
    <td>Item</td>
    <td>Cost</td>
    <td>Weight</td>
    <td>Availability</td>
</tr>
    </thead>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gtxmqvov/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try adding a class to  then add into CSS as thead.class. I am not sure since there doesn't seem to have any errors with your code.

Comment: an example to trhe person asking the question might help